# Delphi 10.4 Exception EComponentError. A component name <name> already exists

Tags: forms, delphi

I'm in the process of trying to migrate a very old project from Delphi 2007 to Delphi 10.4 and I've found that when I try to run the project I get an Exception EComponentError message. I've searched all the previous answers to this on Stack Overflow and various other websites but I can't find anything that actually helps.

Having checked my .dfm files (this happens with every .dfm file in the project) the object is not duplicated anywhere nor is it auto generated in any way leading to multiple items with the same name. It's simply an object dropped on to the form (in Delphi 2007). When I rename the object in the .dfm file it simply moves on to the next object and claims that it's also a duplicate. I've tried renaming about 20 separate objects but the problem keeps moving to the next one. It's not a problem I've ever seen in Delphi 2007.

Does anyone know what's happening and how to fix this?

Comment: A wild off-hand guess: Check if there are two {$R *.dfm } lines in your .PAS source. That would include the .DFM file twice, thus possibly lead to that error...

Comment: @HeartWare Even if there were two such statements in the code, there can only be 1 copy of the Form's DFM in the EXE's resources, and that resource would be loaded only 1 time during Form creation.

Comment: This error usually happens when calling constructor by it's object and not by it's class on runtime. Eq. `Form1.Create(Owner)` and not `TForm1.Create(Owner)`. How about debugging your code starting by placing break point on `TForm` and `TFrame`'s Constructor to find out when this exception are thrown?

Comment: The code is using TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject). I set a breakpoint at the first procedure of the constructor (apologies if FormCreate is not the contructor but I couldn't find anything called Create() ) and it didn't even get that far before the error message appeared.

Comment: @HeartWare Thanks for your suggestion. I checked that and there's no duplicates of {$R .dfm}. You're  help is much appreciated though. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried removing the whole form from the project and then adding it back? Is your project perhaps using INC files for including resources and code to the project? If so you might be adding same units/forms to the project twice. Once with the Delphi IDE and second time with INC file.

Comment: SilverWarrior Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it and it still does the same thing. There doesn't seem to be any INC files that include this form so I'm guessing it's not adding it twice. Thanks for your help though, much appreciated.

Comment: I've now tried renaming all the objects on the form and this seemed to work very briefly until I'd renamed about a dozen of them and then it went back to the objects I'd renamed saying they already exist? Is this a Delphi 10.4 issue? I've never seen this in Delphi 2007 and it's the same project opened in Delphi 10.4

Comment: I've also tried deleting objects on a form, rebuilding the project, closing the IDE, reopening it, adding new objects to the form (all TLabels) with completely new names and then recompiling and rebuilding the project. I still get the same error with the brand new objects. None of this makes any sense to me.

Comment: Try creating a new project and adding form units of the project you are migrating to the new project. It is a long shot but based on your last comments it might be something wrong with the migrated project itself. If adding forms from your old project to the new one still leads to sme problems try creating a brand new test project to se iff it would also cause such problems. if it does then I guess it would be time for doing a complete reinstall of Delphi 10.4 as it would mean something is very wrong with your Delphi installation

Comment: SilverWarrior, thanks I'll give that a go. I've recloned the Delphi 2007 project from it's git repo and opened it in Delphi 10.4 but same issue. I think you're right it's definitely looking like a Delphi 10.4 issue.

Comment: SilverWarrior. I've tried creating an entirely new project and adding my old forms into it but it gets the same result. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I've now tried migrating a completely different project from Delphi2007 to Delphi 11.1 and I have exactly the same issue. If this is Delphi 10.4 issue it's carried on into Delphi 11.1!